# Multiple lines of text in single cell of simple table?

Tags: restructuredtext

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504595/multi-line-table-cell-in-restructuredtext), but I don't want explicit `<br>`s in my cell; I just want it to line-wrap where necessary.

e.g.,

```
================  ============
a short sentence  second cell
a much longer     bottom right
  sentence
================  ============
```

I want "a much longer sentence" to all fit in one cell. I'd need to use *very* long lines of text unless I can find a way to wrap it. Is this possible?

I'm using ~NoTex~ w/ PDF output if relevant.

Comment: It seems the "NoTeX" link no longer does what it once did...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple table style does not support wrapping blocks. Use the [grid style](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#tables) instead, like this:

```
+------------------+--------------+
| a short sentence | second cell  |
+------------------+--------------+
| a much longer    | bottom right |
| sentence         |              |
+------------------+--------------+
```

These tables are more tedious to work with, but they're more flexible. See [the full documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#tables) for details.

Comment: There aren't any other table styles are there? Seems a bit outrageous to me that I should have to be fiddling with ASCII art rather than writing content -- the very thing ReST is supposed to be good for.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Tables are one of ReST's weaknesses, but you can use substitutions or the `.. include ::` directive inside grid table cells to reduce the time spent doing ASCII art, as you accurately put it. (If it's not obvious how to do that, please say so, and I'll update my answer with an example).

Comment: There are tools that will help with your "ascii" art. In Vim for [example](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4112)

Comment: *There aren't any other table styles are there?* - now there are more ("CSV table" and "list table"). See http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#table

Comment: The last example in the [specification of simple tables](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#simple-tables) shows, that the limitation to one line holds only for cells in the *first column*. Cells in subsequent columns accept block-level content (lists, paragraphs, admonitions, ..., but no sections).

Answer (score 14):

There is a clean way.  The issue is by default the columns are set to no-wrap, so that's why you get the scroll.  To fix that you have to override the css with the following:

```
/* override table no-wrap */
.wy-table-responsive table td, .wy-table-responsive table th {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Don't think this is a CSS problem. It's to do with how to format tables in [reStructuredText](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText).

Comment: Although this answer is not 100% accurate for a "Simple Table" it did answer my question of how to enable word wrap for my ".. csv-table::" imports.

Comment: This solution is better than messing around with ASCII grid styles...

Answer (score 6):

A workaround for this problem is to use a replace directive:

```
================  ============
a short sentence  second cell
|long_sentence|   bottom right
================  ============

.. |long_sentence| replace:: a much longer sentence
```

Answer (score 3):

The example [ddbeck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16578179/2521743) presented may work because the sentence is to short. In the case of the lenght of the sentence dont fit in the screen, the sentence will not continue in a new line. Instead, the table will create a horizontal scrollbar. There is no clean way for solving this problem. You can implicit use pipe to implicitly change line like you saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540865/2521743).

If you want alternatives to write your tables in restructuredtext, more pratical ways, you can check it in [Sphinx/Rest Memo](http://rest-sphinx-memo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ReST.html#tables).

Comment: Do you mean the [grid table](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#grid-tables) syntax? There is no limit to the size of a table cell, so any content should fit.

Answer (score 1):

The [list-table](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#list-table) syntax may be suited here:

```
.. list-table::

   * - a short sentence
     - second cell
   * - A "much" longer
       sentence.
       
       A table cell may also contain more than one paragraph.
       
     - bottom right
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a python utility to format fixed-width plaintext table with multiline cells: https://github.com/kkew3/tabulate. Hope it helps.