# Can I create a multi-line cell using list-table?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using sphinx to build my lib diocumentation and serve it via ReadTheDoc website.
I'm using the `list-table` directive to create table of data sources of my project.

I would like the first column to be a multi-line cell, is it possible ?

This does the trick but it's just empty lines not real multi-line cells:

```
.. list-table:: Title
   :header-rows: 1

   * - Heading row 1, column 1
     - Heading row 1, column 2
     - Heading row 1, column 3
   * - Row 1, column 1
     - Row 1, column 2
     - Row 1, column 3
   * - 
     - Row 2, column 2
     - Row 2, column 3
```

Note: everything in the second columns of my table is a reference to scientific article (so it's super long) I cannot afford to use the rst table syntax like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13540865/6734243):

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 |
+==========+==========+==========+
| | Item 1 |          |          |
| | Item 2 |          |          |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: No. Only grid tables support multi-line cells. Reference: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#table-directives

Comment: sad but understandable, If you write down this comment as answer I will accept it

Comment: The term "multi-line" is a bit misleading: it is easy to create cells that contain several lines (e.g. a line-block) with the "list-table" directive. So, the grid-table in the second example can be easily reproduced with a list-table. However, *row-spanning* cells are only possible with the [grid-table](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#grid-tables) syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Only grid tables support multi-line cells. Reference: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#table-directives